# Email Report: how to display thousands of emails in a report?

Tags: email, reports

I want to generate a report after the admin send emails. The report contains

- Subject
- Message
- A list containing the names and emails of all the recipients
- A flag that tells whether the email is sent or not, since the email server can't send all emails at once
- A timestamp

My question is, suppose you send up to 10 000 recipients per day, is there a way to display them in a report without messing up the page?

Comment: What is the goal of the report? Which actions can / should the user execute after seeing the report?

Comment: @RickP there's only 4 admins that can see the report, the server can handle 400 emails per hour, the admins might need to send 10 000 emails per day. That would take the server 25h to send them all. The admins should know who received the emails and who didn't yet and if something goes wrong they should be able to resend the email

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is, suppose you send up to 10 000 recipients per day, is there a way to display them in a report without messing up the page?

Yes. One way is to display information in a progressive fashion.

The top Level displays the primary reporting information and on drill-down present ever more detailed information.

You didn't mention it but there is much more information to display.

```
Amt in Email List | Emails Sent % | Emails Opened / % | Responses

10,000            | 1000      10% | 100            1% | 10
```

The chances of the manager just wanting to blindly scan a list of 10,000 is very low. You need to find out what specifically the person is trying to ascertain from the information.

Also if you're sending that many emails it is probably organized into campaigns. You may be sending the same email (or variations on a theme) multiple times to the recipient.

- "UX Seminar - Early Bird Prices"
- "UX Seminar - Time is Running out for Early Bird Prices"
- "UX Seminar - Tomorrow"

Answer (score 1):

It reminds me a lot of Mailchimps mail campaigns as well as Mixpanel. On both platforms you get an overview of all the campaigns, displayed as list items on which you can display the progress of how many people have received the mail.

Upon expanding these list items you can show the actions that admins can execute to follow up on, for example, sending the mails to users that haven't received the mail yet.